# Lazy-loading Foundation Drilldown Menu

Tags: zurb-foundation, lazy-loading, drilldown, zurb-foundation-6

I'm trying to replace instances of jsTree with [Foundation's drilldown menu](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/drilldown-menu.html) as it has better benefits, but in some places I'm utilizing [jsTree's lazy loading](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/) however there's no option for this in Foundation.  Is there any way of doing this, or does anybody know if it's been done before?

I had the initial parent-level list populating, but the drilldown functionality wasn't being applied after calling Foundation.Drilldown(), and I haven't been able to figure out the next-level items yet.

```
$(function(){
    var tree = $("ul#tree_id");
    $.getJSON("/url/",function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data){
            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                var node = document.createElement("li");
                $(node).html(value.text);
                tree.prepend($(node))
            });
        }
        var elem = new Foundation.Drilldown(tree);
    });
});
```

Thanks.